# UITableViewCell with a lot of subviews or with a single view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, subview

I'm new in iOS programming that's why I'm looking for the most efficient solution to my problem.
What I want to achieve  is to display in `UITableViewCell` with a name (some text) and under each name some filled little rectangles with a number inside, similar to badges.

My first idea is to create a `UIView` that will represent the badge and in a custom `UITableViewCell` I will add these rectangles as `subviews`.
The second idea is to create only one `UIView` that will draw all the little rectangles.

My question is, which is the better performing solution knowing that:

- the number of cells will be max. 20 and the total number of rectangles no more than 50
- The number of rectangles displayed in a cell is different
- I want to reuse the cells, so I have to update/redraw the cell content for each row
- I want to avoid the cell selection view problem that "hides" the subviews

Of course any other solution is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
hxx

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not creating cell in `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` Here you can defines your custom type cell which will also reuse and whenever you want you can add the different thing to cell like this.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UILabel *RequestSentTo;
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    RequestSentTo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 2, 286, 40)];
    RequestSentTo.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    RequestSentTo.tag = 200;
    RequestSentTo.numberOfLines = 3;
    RequestSentTo.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    RequestSentTo.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    RequestSentTo.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:RequestSentTo];
} else {
    RequestSentTo=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:200];
}
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Shift Request for "];
[string appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ by ",dateStr] attributes:nil]];
[string appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dr. %@",notificationsObj.doctorName] attributes:purpleTextAttributes]];//purpl
RequestSentTo.attributedText=string;
RequestSentTo.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
RequestSentTo.numberOfLines = 3;
```

Whenever you want you can add the things you want with reusing cell. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. As I wrote, the number of rectangles in the cell is different so I cannot replace them with a single UILabel. Following your solution I would need to add dinamically labels (views) depending on the number of rectangles in the cell. It is ok, but I'm afraid that it will consume too much memory.

Comment: how many rectangles you can have it depends on that you can dynamically create uilabels and add tag on it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need is called custom cell

Here is good tutorial  for it

[customize table view cells for uitableview](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

Comment: Yes, I know, but the question is what to add in the custom cell. A single view that draws the rectangles or a separate view for each rectangle?

Comment: it's better to have container UIView and separate view for rectangle inside this container UIView

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest is to sub class the UITableViewCell and make the customization u need in it.The customized view can have a label and rectangles below it.

The rectangles can be small custom buttons with background images (if you have any or give it a background color) and title as your number.You would have to ,however calculate their width based on the width of your table to accomodate  the maximum number of rectangles.

You can disable the selection of the table in the xib or you can do it programmatically like so `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` and do not implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

I have followed the approach of subclassing the cell for my tables to customize their look and feel and it works good.I hope this helps.

A Good tutorial to begin with subclassing can be found here

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/

Comment: So, you say to add the rectangles as subviews. But what about memory consumption? I don't need to have UI objects in the cell since what I need is only to display numbers with coloured background.

Comment: In order to display any sort of text on any view you need a label.This label has to be a subview of the given view.At any given time in your table only the visible cells will in memory.That is what is the function of "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier".If you need to display text ,adding a label as a subview is inevitable.

Comment: Generally yes, I need a UILabel object, but if I subclass an UIView, in the drawRect method I can use the NSString's drawAtPoint to draw a text on it. So I don't need allways labels to display text on a cell. But my problem is that, if a cell is reused, its drawRect method is called every time a new value is assigned to it or only one time when the cell object is created.

Comment: Oh is it!!,Thank you i learnt a new thing today.I wasn't aware of this.Apologies to incorrectly aver creating a label as inevitable.If i have understood correctly you need to call drawRect when you wish,may be you can try [self.view setNeedsDisplay],this would give a call to the drawRect.

Answer (score 0):

2 methods come into my mind.

1. You can put the components as subview inside `UITableViewCell`(Through XIB or programatically subclassing `UITableViewCell`) and use it in `UITableView`.
2. You can subclass `UITableViewCell`, and override the `-(void)drawRect` method and draw all the components that you wish to be displayed on cell.

Comment: Yes, your second method is nearly what I imagined in order to draw the rectangles on the view but as a subview of a UITableViewCell subclass. What is not clear for me, how to force the cell to refresh itself and to draw the corresponding rectangles when the cell gets reused.

Comment: UITableViewCell has a method to force drawing (setNeedsLayout method)

Answer (score 0):

See if can help.
You can create a new class extends to UITableViewCell, which means to rewrite UITableViewCell as your own cell named as MyTestCell.
And in this Cell you call create your properties, like labels and views, and add those to your new cell.
like add this to MyTestCell.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILable *myLable1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *mySubview1;

MyTestCell.m
_myLable1 = .....
_mySubview = .....

[self addSubview: _myLbale1];
[self addSubview: _mySubview1];


And when use, u can work like this

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableview dequeReuseID:CellIdentifier]; 
if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [MyTableViewCell alloc] init.........
} 

//And you can sign your property here in your cell
cell.myLable1 = ....
cell.myView1 = .....

return cell;

}
```

If your strings add to the lable is different,make the lable.height is different. you can use code like this

```
 CGSize labelSize = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0f]
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 100)
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];   //check your lableSize
 UILabel *patternLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 157, labelSize.width, labelSize.height)];   
 patternLabel.text = str;
 patternLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 patternLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0f];
 patternLabel.numberOfLines = 0;// must have
 patternLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;// must have
```

add this to your cell, and make it dynamically resize your lable as well as your cell! And also you have to dynamically set high for your tableView Row height.(Do know what is dynamically resize?)
See this:
     rewrite the method setMyLable1 in MyTableViewCell.m

```
 -(void)setMyLable1:(UILable*)aLable
 {
   //in here when never your sign your alabel to your cell (like this : cell.myLable1) this method will be call and u can get the size of your string and set this label's height
   //get string size  StringSzie

   [_myLable1 setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,stringSize.width,stringSize.height)];

   //And resize your cell as well
   [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,_myLable1.frame.size.width+20,_myLable1.frame.size.height+20)];

   //done!!!

 }
```

OK you get a automactically reszie cell for yourself and you have to dynamically reset height for your row in tableView too!!!!!